# Symfony container Definition method is not called for not injected service

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, backend, ioc-container

Before I start any discussion on Symfony's Github, I would like to clarify the situation
and make sure that I really found an issue for which there is no solution.

When we have a service container definition and that definition is not injected anywhere
then any of its methods configured to be called by `addMethodCall` within a compiler pass - won't be called.
Even if we make a service to be `public` (which preserves service in container) - it won't change the situation.

Of course it makes sense, but according to that behaviour I cannot achieve the following implemenation:

- There is `Service A` which has related compiler pass and it is injected into some other service
- Compiler pass configures `Service A` definition to call `someMethodA()` by applying its `addMethodCall()` function
- `someMethod()` is adding instances of `Service B` to a collection existing within `Service A`
- Until now it works perfectly fine, but...
- Any of `Service B` instances are not injected anywhere (they are only collected by `Service A` method within its collection)
- Instances of `Service B` also contains their own compiler passes which the same as for `Service A` configure their definitions to call `someMethodB()` which are also collecting some other services
- Unfortunately, according to the fact described at the beginning, about definitions not calling configured methods while they are not injected - makes a problem of not calling `someMethodB()`, so all instances of `Service B` have empty collections of related services, preventing the application from working correctly

**Question:** how can I make sure that not injected service definition will call configured method, so it contains everything what is needed (like its inner collection),
when some other service will take an instance of this definition, expecting it to have its collection initialized?

**Notice:** I was trying to set not injected services to be `public` and not `lazy`, I also tried to register them manually in the container and running related compiler passes before removal processes to be 100% sure that they are in place (and actually they are, I don't have problem with missing service, but with the fact that definition is not calling its configured method).

Symfony **4.4.21**

Comment: Too many words!  Make a simple test case, check it into github and provide a link.